# How to Make Sure My Custom ClaimsPrincipal Sticks Around In ASP.NET MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, security, asp.net-web-api, wif, .net-4.5

I am creating a custom ***ClaimsPrincipal*** that has additional claims using a custom ***AuthenticationManager***.  It appears that in ASP.NET 4.5 the ***AuthenticationManager*** is not automatically invoked and you have to manually invoke it. I have seen posts that suggest you do this in the ***PostAuthenticateRequest***. My code looks like this in the Global.asax:

```
protected void Application_OnPostAuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User =
        FederatedAuthentication.FederationConfiguration.IdentityConfiguration.ClaimsAuthenticationManager.Authenticate("none",
            System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User as ClaimsPrincipal);
}
```

I am using Forms Authentication with cookies.  The current principal gets set correctly when the PostAuthenticateRequest is fired. The problem is that when the next request comes in to the ASP.NET Web API the custom claims are lost. I am using Web API for AJAX requests in a single page application (SPA). I suspect that what is in the current ClaimsPrincipal is being overwritten by what is in the cookie, but I am not sure. I am not using an inherited ClaimsPrincipal for type-safe retrieval of custom claims. I am just adding new claims which are subsequently lost somewhere in the process. What is the proper way to setup a custom ClaimsPrincipal so the additional claims are not loss between requests.

Comment: Are you casting back to your custom claims principal when you retrieve the object?

Comment: Sorry I was not very clear by what I meant by a custom claims principal in my question. I will update it. I am not inheriting from the ClaimsPrincipal for type safe retrieval of claims. I am just adding additional claims which are lost at some point in the process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the solution I came up with. First I used the FormsAuthentication_OnAuthenticate event instead of the Application_OnPostAuthenticateRequest event. I get the cookie to retrieve the authenticated users name and build a new claims principal with the claims I  want to add. I do not add the roles as claims because the system adds them later in the authentication process and ends up duplicating them.  This allows me to add custom claims to the principal for future processing in the application.

```
public void FormsAuthentication_OnAuthenticate(object sender, FormsAuthenticationEventArgs args)
{
    if (FormsAuthentication.CookiesSupported)
    {
        if (Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName] != null)
        {
            try
            {
                FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(
                  Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName].Value);

                SaClaimsSecurity security = new SaClaimsSecurity();
                //Do not add roles here because the security framework adds them
               //somewhere else in the chain and will duplicate roles
               ClaimsPrincipal principal = security.CreateClaimsPrincipalWithoutRoles(ticket.Name);
                args.User = principal;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                // Decrypt method failed.
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
       throw new HttpException("Cookieless Forms Authentication is not " +
                                    "supported for this application.");
    }
}
```